# Radio Button Helper - Default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table rooms and I have a field `type`(Single, Double). I want to use a radio button for this field. So, I am using it like this:

```
<% form_for(@room) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, "Single" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, "Double" %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine for edit view. The problem is that for the new view, I want to default the radio button to "Single". For this code, no value is checked for the new view.

I am now adjusting that with condition check

```
<% form_for(@room) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, "Single", :checked => @room.new_or_single? %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, "Double" %>
<% end %>
```

Room model

```
def new_or_single?
  type.nil? or type == "Single"
end
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You can set default value for type on 'single' in database schema or in the constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set default :type in constructor

```
def new
  @room = Room.new(:type => "Single")
end
```

Comment: You also may want to consider changing your field name from 'type' to 'room_type'.  The column name 'type' is a field that Active Record uses for inheritance.  It may cause you problems later on:  http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/MagicFieldNames